# Weird text when downloading Anaconda

Tags: command-line, curl, anaconda

I was following this link to install anaconda in Ubuntu 18.04.1:

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-the-anaconda-python-distribution-on-ubuntu-18-04

When I tried to download anaconda using curl using the following command (which downloads the latest version of anaconda rather than the version shown in the link):

```
$ curl -0 https://repo.anaconda.com/archive/Anaconda3-5.2.0-Linux-x86_64.sh
```

I got the following weird text in the terminal which continued to spew out for several minutes:

[image]

Afterwards "c62;c62" was displayed repeatedly in the terminal (but I did not type it)?

Anyway this all seemed to be very weird so I hit ctrl-C to cancel the process?

Is this normal?
Is not should I take any corrective measures regarding this?

Comment: That's `curl -O` in the link you gave. Capital `O`, not the digit `0`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's perfectly correct behaviour as `curl` by default outputs the contents of the download to the terminal, which is not what you need here, just use it like this:

```
curl https://repo.anaconda.com/archive/Anaconda3-5.2.0-Linux-x86_64.sh > anaconda.sh
```

or use the `-o` flag of curl:

```
curl -o anaconda.sh https://repo.anaconda.com/archive/Anaconda3-5.2.0-Linux-x86_64.sh
```

or preserve the full name of the downloaded script by using the `-O` flag (which is actually what's mentioned in the tutorial you linked to)

```
curl -O https://repo.anaconda.com/archive/Anaconda3-5.2.0-Linux-x86_64.sh
```

Comment: The tutorial mentioned `-O`, aka `--remote-name`, *not* `-o` aka `--output`.

Comment: @muru Ah, my bad xD

Answer (score 1):

As [already noted](https://askubuntu.com/a/1060704/250300), your `curl` invocation is wrong. Moreover, `curl` does not have to be available in every Ubuntu installation.

However, `wget` should be available on any Ubuntu since the package [`ubuntu-standard`](https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/ubuntu-standard) depends on it. The syntax to download a file is even easier with `wget`:

```
wget https://repo.anaconda.com/archive/Anaconda3-5.2.0-Linux-x86_64.sh
```